# Javascript name validation

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

I have a javascript function written to validate a field on my form. This function is supposed to make sure the field is not empty, does not exceed the limit of 35 characters and only contains alphabetic characters and a hyphen(-). I had code to make sure the field is not empty and that it does not exceed 35 characters which worked fine but i added code to validate the field to the usable characters and i tested it out by leaving the field empty to make sure that still worked but when i hit the submit button the function didn't seem to validate at all, didn't give me an alert and just submitted. Here is my code:

```
function validateFamily()
{
var family=document.getElementById('family');
var stringf = document.getElementById('family').value;
if (family.value=="")
    {
     alert("Family name must be filled out");
     return false;
    }
else if (document.getElementById('family').value.length > 35)
    {
        alert("Family name cannot be more than 35 characters");
        return false;
    }
else if (/[^a-zA-Z\-\]/.test( stringf ))
    {
        alert("Family name can only contain alphanumeric characters and hypehns(-)")
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

<form name="eoiform" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi" onsubmit="return validateFamily() && validateGiven() && validateMaleFemale() && validDate() && validateAddress() && validatePost() && validateParent() && validateWork() && validateHome() && validateMob() && validateCheckBoxes();">

<b>Student's Family Name</b> 
<br>
<input type="text" id="family" name="family" /><?php echo $strmsgf; ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

Could anyone show me how to fix my code?

Comment: does an alert("Alert"); in the beginning of validateFamily() function works?

Comment: The console log in your browser is something that you may want to take a look for debugging this type of situation, what does it show?

Comment: @konnection if you mean "Family name must be filled out" than if i take out the usable character validation code than yes it works just fine but currently it doesn't.

Comment: @konnection also how would i bring up the console? i am using chrome to view my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:

Sorry, the problem is with your regex, i missed that, change to this its fully working:

```
  var ck_password =  /^[A-Za-z0-9-]/;

            if(!ck_password.test(stringf))
            {

                alert("Family name can only contain alphanumeric characters and hypehns(-)")

            }
```

Console in chrome, go to the OPTIONS in the right top coner, select TOOLS, then DEVELOPER TOOLS.

Comment: try now, or just change your regex to the one in my answer in your own code. hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression is broken. You've escaped the closing square bracket around the character set. Try this:

```
else if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/.test( stringf ))
```

Also, there's a lot of weird clutter in there that's annoying but not fatal: How many times do you really need to call getElementById('family') in that method? Once.

```
if (stringf=="")
{
    alert("Family name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
else if (stringf.length > 35)
{
    alert("Family name cannot be more than 35 characters");
    return false;
}
else if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/.test( stringf ))
{
    alert("Family name can only contain alphanumeric characters and hypehns(-)")
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: There's a lot of weird clutter in there that's annoying but not fatal: You can get rid of those series of `return false;`-lines, if you add `else{return true}` at the end of `else if`s and change last boolean to false. (_The sarcasm here is just plain joking_)

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename submit button, rid of id and name "submit" (rename to "doSubmit" or smth), it can cause problems and conflict with event "submit" of form.

Comment: Such conflict would be serious bug in a browser.