# Javascript regex to validate users profile name

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

How can I validate a name in Javascript using Regex? I tried with /^([a-zA-Z.]){3,50}$/ this validation expression but it does not completely satisfy my needs.

Valid Names can be (Total Length between 3 and 50)

- John
- Antony Simon
- Kevin M D
- James.K

Invalid names can be

- 121212
- aaa12212
- 3434fgfgf
- James..
- James .

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839024/javascript-name-validation

Answer (score 2):

First try to decide what will be your validation criteria one by one.....
1.Is it just to check string length Length between 3 and 50
2.Is it just to check string length Length between 3 and 50 and just contain characters
3.Is it just to check string length Length between 3 and 50 and just contain characters
 '.' sysmbol
etc

Without deciding your proper scenario you can't build a regex

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
/^([a-zA-Z. ]){2,49}[a-zA-Z]$/
```

Comment: +1, but you don't need capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work ..

```
var str = "James..";
var regx =  /^(([a-zA-Z](\s|\.)?)*){3,50}$/;
regx.test(str);
```